# Bash create text files containing the name of the folder

Tags: bash, shell, file

I have a folder called FolderName, containing a lot of png files, not necessarily in order, for example

```
01.png, 32.png ...
```

and I want to create a .txt file for every single one of them, with the same names as the png files,

```
01.txt, 32.txt ...
```

and all the text files to contain just the name of the folder.

I have no idea on how to do this, and I've spent the last 30 minutes reading about bash scripts. Please help.

All I managed to do so far is

```
#!/bin/bash

folder=/home/user/folder/

for file in $("$folder")
do
   name=$(basename "$file" .txt)
   printf '%s\n' "$line" >"$file".txt

done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this :

```
#!/bin/bash
folder="/home/user/folder"
for filePng in $folder/*
do
 fileTxt=${filePng/png/txt}
 dirname "$filePng" > "$fileTxt"
done
```

Some explanation :

- `$folder/*` expands to the list of files, separated by whitespaces. `for` will iterate through that list.
- `${variable/pattern/substition}` is bash string substitution

[EDIT] I'm supposing the .txt files are located in `$folder`.

Comment: I get : ./small_script.sh: line 6: /bin: Is a directory
./small_script.sh: line 6: /boot: Is a directory
./small_script.sh: line 6: /vmlinuz: Permission denied
./small_script.sh: line 6: /vmlinuz.old: Permission denied
Was what you wrote the whole script?

Comment: No, so I have the PNG files and I want to create the Txt files, in the same folder, each txt file containing the name of the folder.

Comment: Ah. I wrote something that would replace your loop, I'll update my message (obviously, `$folder` was not defined when you ran it)

Comment: What does your script do exactly? It just gives a long list of no such file or directory.

Comment: `$folder/*` returns the list of files under $folder. If you don't define `$folder`, the bash variable substitution will interpret  it as `/*`, hence the `/bin` and `/boot` warnings you observed.    `for file in "$folder/*"` will iterate through that list.   `fileTxt=${filePng/png/txt}` replaces "png" in the string $filePng (which is, at that point, the name of an image - 4.png) by "txt" (thus returning "4.txt" in our example). `dirname $file`  returns the name of the path to a file, excluding its basename (`dirname a/b/c.txt` returns `a/b`). I'm saving its output in the matching txt filename.